# Different widgets in generated symfony module for editing or creating an object

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

In the following generator.yml, I can change the class for the form used in the backend. However, I would like to have different forms for when editing an existing object, or when creating a new one.

When editing an object, I want to unset the field 'onset', without losing it when creating a new object. Is this possible, and if so, how?

```
JobeetCategory:
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
    test: { type: string(255) }
    onset:  { type: boolean }


generator.yml:
config:
  actions: ~
  fields:  ~
  list:
    title: Category Management
  filter:  ~
  form:    
      class: TestForm
  edit:
    title: Editing Category "%%name%%"
  new:
    title: New Category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally set or unset widgets inside your form class, depending on wether your object is new or being edited:

```
<?php

class JobeetCategoryForm extends BaseJobeetCategoryForm {

  public function configure() {
    $this->setWidgets(array(
      'onset' => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox()
      // other widgets...
    ));
    $this->setValidators(array(
      'onset' => new sfValidatorBoolean()
      // other validators...
    ));
    if (!$this->object->isNew()) {
      // we are editing an existing category
      unset($this['onset']);
    }
    // ...
  }

}
```